# Glass material: object shown with strange artifacts

Tags: materials, transparency

I have an object that I've built using many circles, and then connecting the edge loops between them. I've tried to apply a glassy material, playing with transparency values, but the problem is that the parts where there are the circles are drawn differently:

[image]

I've already adjusted the normals. How could I eliminate these artifacts?

**Update**

There are no faces inside the edge loops. This is how the mesh looks in edit mode:

[image]

Comment: Try selecting all and removing doubles from `W` menu. If that doesn't help please [upload the file](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), at least part of the problem model.

Answer (score 3):

It looks to me like there are still faces left inside your mesh.
Like this:[image]

What you need to do is delete those inside faces.  This can be done by just selecting the center vertex of each circle and hitting X on the keyboard and then selecting delete vertices.  Your final clean mesh should look like this:

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: You could also select those faces with *Select Non-Manifold* operator from *Select* menu or `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`Shift`+`M`

Comment: It's strange because there are no faces inside the edge loops. I created some circles and united them with w -> bridge edge loops. Check my post, I uploaded a new image that shows the wireframe structure of the object.